# how to connect to sqlplus using perl script

Tags: perl, unix

In unix the normal procedure that we use to connect to sqlplus is like this

```
sqlplus ${user}/${password}@${server} my_file.sql >> $Logfile 2>&1
```

where im appending all the info in the above command  to the log file `$Logfile`

Now in perl i know how to connect to sqlplus and execute a sql script i used something like

```
system("sqlplus -L ${user}/${password}@${server} my_file.sql")
```

but using `system` we cannot send an info to a log file it will only give the return status i want to track the info of the executed command like we do in unix Is there a way to do this. Please help Thanks

Comment: Why you can not use system("sqlplus -L ${user}/${password}\@${server} my_file.SQL >> $Logfile 2>&1")

Comment: can i use like that in perl? let me try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is far better to access the database using [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI) and [`DBD::Oracle`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD::Oracle) rather than shelling out to run the interactive tool *SQL*Plus*.

But if you insist on creating a separate process to manipulate your database, then an identical command passed to `system` will achieve the same results.

I have assumed that you want the at sign `@` in there literally? Like this

```
system("sqlplus -L ${user}/${password}\@${server} my_file.sql >> $Logfile 2>&1")
```

Or you could use backticks:

```
open my ($log_fh), '>', $Logfile;

print $log_fh `sqlplus -L ${user}/${password}\@${server} my_file.sql`;
```

Comment: thanks a lot Borodin im totally new to perl this is what happens when your lead puts you in something totally alien to you assuming unix and perl are the same :) anyways thanks a lot any doubts ill get back to u

Comment: @user2647888: You're welcome. In general, when possible, it's far better for several reasons to do something natively in Perl than to use `system` to call the shell or an external program.

Comment: If you are struggling to get started with `DBI` then we can help if you show us the contents of `my_file.sql`

Comment: Hi Borodin my sql file can be as simple as `select 'xxx' FROM DUAL`
Now my doubt is if my sql has any errors i want it in the $log_fh.. is it posibble?

Comment: Then you *definitely* need to use `DBI`. Take a look at the documentation. The sequence is `DBI->connect`, `$dbh->prepare`, `$sth->execute`, then if the statement was a `SELECT` you do `$sth->fetch` one or more times. It's very clean, even though the module documentation may appear intimidating because there are a lot of options.

Comment: I'm sorry, I overlooked your question. Yes, you can set `DBI` to `die`, `warn`, or just return a *false* status on any error. But you need to open and write a log file from Perl - it won't happen automatically.